# Light blue highlighting of a variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Why does a variable starting with a lower case s, followed by a capital letter gets highlighted with light blue.

For example, variable cAngle remains white, while the variable sAngle get coloured light blue.

I will also attach a printscreen of the two.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you enter another variable after sAngle ?

Comment: It is the same as cAngle - white. If you meant writing it bellow sAngle.

Comment: I mean, if you enter a new variable below sAngle, does sAngle change its color?

Comment: Probably because your editor is configured to recognise an identifier with that form as the name of a static variable, and static variables are light blue in the colour scheme you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably use a syntax highlighter in vs-code that uses some form of [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Sometimes s followed by a capital is used for static variables. vs-codes syntax highlighter detects this and using some colour scheme (light blue in your case) changes its colour.

Answer (score 0):

Usually variables starting from lower case 's' and followed by capital letters are treated as variables that contain string. It's way to know that it's a string variable.

It will also be true for boolean value. e.g. bIsBoolean = True; where you start variable name with 'b'.

Since you are using syntax highlighter it will use color scheme for these variables.